# OpenGL ES 2.0 Implementing glMultMatrixf

Tags: opengl-es

I am working on porting GLU for OpenGL ES 2.0. Because the version I have seen for ES uses 1.1 there are a few functions that are not in 2.0 and I was hoping to get some help with this. Per the OpenGL [Spec](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/)...

> glMultMatrix — multiply the current matrix with the specified matrix

Ok great, so we are passing a matrix and I assume we can assume that it is 4x4 (xyzw). But what matrix is it multiplying? Is this the gl_position?

Anyone have an example of how to port this function?

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL ES 1.1, the current matrix is the one at the top of the current matrix stack.  There are several matrix stacks and you select one of them like this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

or

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

The matrix stack concept does not exist in 2.0.

Yes, the matrix is always 4 x 4.

There is a good open source implementation of GLU here:

```
http://code.google.com/p/glues/
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice, as for the link that implementation does not use ES 2.0. That looks very similar in fact to the one I am using. The problem is I am trying to port to 2.0 and I don't know how to port the old 1.1 es functions. I think this does help though because I would assume glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); just equals a normal projection transformation matrix.